# Meteor - Publish a collection based on the users status

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to publish the classes collection for users who have `accountStatus.isUserAccountActive: true`. My current code publishes the users who are active but then the entire classes collection. Can someone please show me what I'm doing wrong?

```
Meteor.publish('classList', function (group) {
  if (Roles.userIsInRole(this.userId, ['is_teacher'], group)) {
    return [
    Meteor.users.find({roles:'is_student', "accountStatus.isUserAccountActive": true}, 
      {fields: {
        "profile.firstName": 1, 
        "profile.familyName": 1,
        roles: 1, 
        "accountStatus.isUserAccountActive": 1
      }
    }),
    classes.find({teacherUserId: this.userId},
      {fields: {
        "studentUserId": 1,
        "class": 1
      }})
    ];
  } else {

    // user not authorized. do not publish secrets
    this.stop();
    return;

  }
});
```

Comment: I don't see anything apparent. It's difficult to tell without seeing some concrete example. Can you post a document that is published and souldn't be and the `userId` for which the document was published? Try to log the `userId` or run the query in a `meteor shell` session.

Comment: Hi MasterAm. Thanks for responding. My interpretation of the code above is that it's publishing the users where users are `"accountStatus.isUserAccountActive": true` and then it's publishing all the classes collection.The classes collection isn't contingent on the collection above. I think I need an if statement that says, if `"accountStatus.isUserAccountActive": true` then publish all those student accounts.

Comment: Do you want to publish classes where the `teacherUserId` is the current user's id and the `studentUserId` belongs to a user with a `accountStatus.isUserAccountActive` status of `1`? If so, then you are trying to perform what is known as a `join`, and that is a pain point with MongoDB.  This cannot be easily done. You can either de-normalize the data (and then you have to sync it as it changes) or perform the join manually on the client (show the class if you can find the user and the user's account is active), use a package such as `publish-composite` or MongoDB's aggregation.

Comment: Yes, that sounds correct. What do you mean by de-normalize the data. Do you mean I should put everything into one schema?

Comment: Nope. De-normalization is having multiple copies of the same data. Database normalization is the reverse action - eliminating duplication. De-normalization has its own costs in storage space, added complexity and consistency, to name a few, but it does offer some gains in performance in many cases. There are multiple architectural models to generate de-normalized data, but its beyond the scope of this discussion. There is a lot of reading material on meteor+mongo+joins and mongo+de-normalization.

Comment: Thanks MasterAM. This apparently just got tricky. From the limited reading I've just done, it sounds like there is no silver bullet. Each solution has pros and cons. Since this is a basic MVP application, to test an idea could you offer a simple workaround approach that would be easy to implement?

Comment: You could set the user status per-class instead of globally, which would eliminate the need for this join. Otherwise, the trade-offs remain: client side join, server side reactive-join, de-normalization or advanced architectural pattern like event-sourcing+CQRS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should get you what you want:

```
Meteor.publish('classList', function (group) {
  if (Roles.userIsInRole(this.userId, ['is_teacher'], group)) {
    var users = Meteor.users.find({roles:'is_student', "accountStatus.isUserAccountActive": true}, 
      {fields: {
        "profile.firstName": 1, 
        "profile.familyName": 1,
        roles: 1, 
        "accountStatus.isUserAccountActive": 1
      }
    }); // Get active students.

    // Get the user ids of active students.
    var userIdsWhoAreActive = users.fetch().map( function( user ) {
        return user._id;
    });
    return [ users,
    classes.find({teacherUserId: this.userId, studentUserId: { $in: userIdsWhoAreActive },
      {fields: {
        "studentUserId": 1,
        "class": 1
      }})
    ];
  } else {

    // user not authorized. do not publish secrets
    this.stop();
    return;

  }
});
```

In English, I think the second query reads: "Get me all classes where the teacherUserId is the current user's id and the studentUserId is in the array of active student users"

Comment: Great. Thanks, Stephen. I'm not sure if there is a downside to this, based on the MasterAM comments but it seems to be working. Thanks heaps!

Comment: I believe the drawback is that as you add users it wouldn't reactively update your classes cursor, but I can't imagine it's going to come up often.

Comment: Ahh, ok. Thanks. It will do for where I'm up to. Thanks agian!

Comment: No problem - in case you're interested, there's a good blog post explaining how to do exactly what you're asking for here: https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/reactive-joins-in-meteor/

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look. It might be a little over my head. Following on from this, is it possible to publish a collection twice in one publish. I've tried something like this but it doesn't seem to work `return [ users,
    classes.find({studentUserId: { $in: userIdsWhoAreActive },
      {fields: {
        "studentUserId": 1,
        "class": 1
      }}),
    classes.find({teacherUserId: this.userId})
    ];`

Comment: No, you'd have to do an $or and then do the filtering the way you'd want it client-side.

Comment: Does that create security issues? Sorry for the noob question?

Comment: It certainly could - totally depends on your data/data structure.

Comment: OK. I'll have a play and see what happens. Thanks for all your help!